# Does a that-clause as appositive after a plural noun call for a definite article before it?

Tags: appositives

Why there is no definite article before "claims' in the following sentence? Does the that-clause after the plural noun 'claims' in the following sentence make it specific?
Or is the noun still generic even though it has been qualified by a that-clause?
Can I use the definite article here? How will the meaning change?

> The union denied claims that it would call off the agitation.

Please explain.

Comment: "denied the claims" would mean they rebutted specific claims made by specific people, "denied claims that..." suggests they denied all claims, saying "whoever says that, you know it's wrong because..."

Answer (score 1):

Because the *that* clause is not a relative clause, but a complement of *claims*.

What was claimed? That it would call off the agitation.

**Edit**: MarcinManhattan points out in a comment that even though the *that* clause is not a relative clause in this case, the question would be equally relevant with a relative clause instead, such as "The union denied claims that had been made by management".

This is true. Generally, where a plural noun is further specified to restrict it to a particular set (for example, in either of these two ways) the article *the* is optional, with little or no difference in meaning.

With *the*, the speaker may be focussing more on the particular instances that meet the specification

Comment: But the definite article might still be omitted even with a relative clause. E.g.: "The union denied claims that had been made by management."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: true, and important. I have expanded my answer.